# Batch script to navigate up a directory path in a loop

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, cmd, path

I have some directory path, say "C:\dir 1\dir2\dir3".  I want in each iteration of a loop to use higher parent directories, i.e. "C:\dir 1\dir2\dir3" then "C:\dir 1\dir2" then "C:\dir 1".

My batch script will only navigate up one level and then is stuck there.
Here is a simplified version of my script:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set FolderPath="C:\dir 1\dir2\dir3"

:DOWHILE
echo Checking contents of !FolderPath!
echo Doing some stuff
echo FolderPath before strip: !FolderPath!
for /d %%X in (!FolderPath!) do set ParentPath="%%~dpX"
echo ParentPath !ParentPath!
Set "FolderPath=!ParentPath!"
echo FolderPath after strip: !FolderPath!
pause
if NOT !FolderPath!=="" goto :DOWHILE

endlocal
```

My console response is:

```
Checking contents of "C:\dir 1\dir2\dir3"
Doing some stuff
FolderPath before strip: "C:\dir 1\dir2\dir3"
ParentPath "C:\dir 1\dir2\"
FolderPath after strip: "C:\dir 1\dir2\"
Press any key to continue . . .
Checking contents of "C:\dir 1\dir2\"
Doing some stuff
FolderPath before strip: "C:\dir 1\dir2\"
ParentPath "C:\dir 1\dir2\"
FolderPath after strip: "C:\dir 1\dir2\"
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The only thing I notice is the lack of \ on my initial path.
I'm very new to batch scripts, so it may be something obvious that I have spent hours missing.

Comment: Succint answer: the `for /d %%X in (!FolderPath!) do set ParentPath="%%~dpX"` stops at the terminal backslash.  To continue stripping folders from the path, you have to remove the terminal backslash with `Set "FolderPath=%ParentPath:~0,-1%"`
'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "FolderPath=C:\dir 1\dir2\dir3"

:DOWHILE
echo Checking contents of %FolderPath%
echo Doing some stuff
echo FolderPath before strip: %FolderPath%
for %%e in ("%FolderPath%") do set "ParentPath=%%~dpe"
echo ParentPath %ParentPath%
Set "FolderPath=%ParentPath:~0,-1%"
if NOT "%FolderPath%"=="%parentpath:~0,2%" echo FolderPath after strip: %FolderPath%&goto DOWHILE

GOTO :EOF
```

The `enabledelayedexpansion` is not required as there is no instance of using a variable whose value changes within a `code block` (parenthesised sequence of commands).

Hence, each `!var!` can be `%var%`.

Preferred syntax is `set "var=value"` which will ensure that any trailing spaces on a line are not included in the value assigned. It's easier to insert required quotes as needed than to manipulate them as they are part of a variable's value.

I changed the `metavariable` from `%%X` to `%%e` because `adfnpstx` are metavariable-modifiers and hence a typo is harder to solve if these characters are used as metavariables.

`%%e` processes a simple quoted string. The string must be quoted since the path contains a space.

`parentpath` will be terminated with a backslash (%%~p produces terminal backslash) So `folderpath` is this, except for the final character (`Set/?` from the prompt or many. many examples on SO for documentation).

The resultant `folderpath` may be `d:`, which you apparently do not wish to process. This is the terminal condition.

Otherwise, `folderpath` will be a directoryname. You need to add a terminal backslash and enclose the resultant string in quotes to use it as it potentially contains a space, ie `"%folderpath%\"` or `"%folderpath%\filemaskorfilename"`.

Note that if you do want to use the root directory of the drive then restore the original position of the `echo FolderPath after…` statement. `d:\` means "the root directory of `d:`" but `d:` means "The current directory of `d:`"

Comment: While that was a lot of good information, it was hard to find the answer to my question among the style guidelines and extra guesses that were not actually relevant.  I mentioned that I stripped down my script to just the problem code.  I do need enabledelayedexpansion in my main script, and my logic to stop the :DOWHILE block was just something simple to demo the problem that unfortunately distracted you with what I might be trying to accomplish.  Since I am new, I would love suggestions on how to better ask questions so that the focus is only on the problem at hand.  Thanks!

Comment: The ad nauseam reference to proved robust preferred syntax/structures is intended to minimise repetition and follow-ups from those who research similar problems in the future. I favour a generalised solution over a custom fit to avoid the `same thing, but in blue` questions. It's an inexact science. We have those who faithfully copy/paste but don't understand `!var!` requires `delayedexpansion`. We have retypers who omit required separators or play with newlines. We've even had people insisting that `::` and `rem` are equivalent.